# How to fire a rowclick event

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i trigger a row click event in ASP.NET GridView

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by row click event? Do you intend to execute a `GridView.RowCommand` Event?

If yes, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx) is a code example with description.

Answer (score 0):

Just check [ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/08/434828.aspx) about clickable grid view.